# Problems installing VirtualBox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to install Oracle’s VirtualBox.

I used **sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-4.2_4.2.4-81684\~Ubuntu\~quantal_i386.deb**

Getting following errors

```
 (Reading database ... 226237 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace virtualbox-4.2 4.2.4-81684~Ubuntu~quantal (using virtualbox-4.2_4.2.4-81684~Ubuntu~quantal_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement virtualbox-4.2 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-4.2:
 virtualbox-4.2 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.13-20ubuntu5.
 virtualbox-4.2 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1.
 virtualbox-4.2 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.1.
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.2 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

libc6, libqtcore4, libqtgui4 these three packages have lower version than the required version. 
Use synaptic package manager to locate these packages latest version and install it, or you can alternatively use "sudo apt-get install package_name"